# Ubuntu 20.04. How to prioritize wireless (or any other network) card?

Tags: wireless, network-manager

There are a lot of similar questions, but all of them ask about prioritizing traffic (with metric as a solution). I want to use only one network card at the same time. For example, if the external card (`wlan1`) is plugged try to use it, else use the internal one (`wlan0`). I tried to use `connection.autoconnect-priority` in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*.nmconnection` files, but it doesn't prioritize connections with different interfaces.
Here is my `connection` section of `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/my_home_from_usb.nmconnection`:

```
id=my_home_usb
uuid=c481eb20-a299-4703-9537-e2e4849e4983
type=wifi
autoconnect-priority=10
interface-name=wlan1
permissions=
timestamp=1581203793
```

and `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/my_home.nmconnection`:

```
[connection]
id=my_home_internal
uuid=9d4cdada-1550-497e-b3b7-a82619bbd072
type=wifi
autoconnect-priority=5
interface-name=wlan0
permissions=
timestamp=1581203793
```

and `nmcli -f NAME,UUID,AUTOCONNECT,AUTOCONNECT-PRIORITY,ACTIVE,DEVICE,STATE,ACTIVE-PATH c` output

```
NAME              UUID                                  AUTOCONNECT  AUTOCONNECT-PRIORITY  ACTIVE  DEVICE   STATE      ACTIVE-PATH                                        
lan               153501bf-9e36-43e8-b63e-67d2d6d18076  yes          3                     yes     eth0     activated  /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2 
my_home_internal  9d4cdada-1550-497e-b3b7-a82619bbd072  yes          5                     yes     wlan0    activated  /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/4 
my_home_usb       c481eb20-a299-4703-9537-e2e4849e4983  yes          10                    yes     wlan1    activated  /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/5
```

So, how can I use only one network card simultaneously?

Comment: Have you tried setting a different `metric` value?

Comment: @Jos Nope, cause using `metric` isn't my case. I want to use only one interface, not all with prioritized traffic.

Comment: You could adapt my `net-o-matic` script: `https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic` It watches the connection, and when the connection drops, does a user-specified thing